# Convergence in probability of the average!!

Tags: probability-theory

I am trying to prove the follow result ($EX$ deonetes the expectation of $X$ and $P(A)$ the probability of the event $A\subset \Omega$ ):

> **Proposition:** Let $(X_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of random variables such that $E(X_{n}^{2})=\int_{\Omega}X_{n}^2 \rightarrow 0$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$. We define $S_{n}:= \sum_{k=1}^{k=n}X_{n}$ and $Y_n=\frac{S_n-ES_n}{n}$. Then the sequence $Y_n$ converges to $0$ in probability.

My attempt is:

Fix $\epsilon\geq 0 $. By Chebyshev inequality we obtain:

$$P(|S_n-ES_n| \geq n \epsilon)\leq \frac{E(|S_n-ES_n|^2)}{n^2\epsilon^2}$$
$$=\frac{E(S_n^2)-(ES_n)^2}{n^2\epsilon^2}$$
$$=\frac{\sum_{j=1}^nE(X_j^2)+2\sum_{1\leq j < k \leq n }E(X_jX_k)-(\sum _{j=1}^nEX_j)^2}{n^2\epsilon^2} $$

That is in order to use the hypothesis $EX_n^2 \rightarrow 0$. But I need an algebraic manipulation in the last inequality to get the result. Can you help me with the conclusion?. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{E(S_n^2)-(ES_n)^2}{n^2\epsilon^2}\leq \frac{ES_n^2}{n^2\epsilon^2}$. By Cauchy -Schwarz inequality $S_n^{2} \leq n\sum X_i^{2}$ so $ES_n^{2} \leq n \sum EX_i^{2}$. Now use the fact  $a_n \to 0$ implies $\frac {a_1+a_2+...+a_n} n \to 0$.

Comment: thank you very much, everything is very clear to me now!!